# Possibilities and limitations of executing a criteria query on a java.net.URL type object

Tags: java, jpa-2.0, criteria-api

I have a database table where I store URLs (*http://google.com* for example). The entity corresponding to the table has a *URL* type field, so I create a criteria query like the following:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = ...
Path<URL> path = ...
cb.equal(path , new URL("http://google.com"));
```

This works as intended, however I want to be able to do something like this:

```
cb.like(path.<String>get("externalForm"), "%google%");
```

Obviously URL hasn't got an *externalForm* field, but has a *toExternalForm()* method instead.

Is this kind of query possible with the API? If yes: how? Or is my best bet to map the URL column to String instead of URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot call methods of persisted values in Criteria queries. JPQL do have same limitation. In the end both of those translate to the SQL query and calling method in arbitrary Java object does not fit too well in.

Also in your case it does not matter do we try to access this via field or method. Reason being that fields in java.net.URL are different from the persistent attributes mapped in your entities. URL fields are not directly persisted (so you cannot query them in SQL), Serializable objects are just persisted via serialization to byte array or similar.

Also, calling equals in java.net.URL can cause surprises: [java.net.url Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29)

Just go with the String as type and keep care that field in database is long enough also for surprisingly long urls.

Comment: I've played with this a bit, but I also came to the conclusion that I'm better off with a String ... not (only) because queries containing _LIKE_ are impossible like this, but because of the damaged _URL.equals(Object)_ method. I've totally forgot about this particular aspect of URLs. I don't know if I will ever need to issue this kind of query, but if not, I'll go with _URI_ instead of URL. Until then: String for the rescue! Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Just a fun fact on URIs and JPA (Hibernate): URLs are mapped automatically by Hibernate without any annotation magic, but URIs are not. A custom type has to be defined. Basically one has to mimic [_UrlType_](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/type/UrlType.html) and [_UrlTypeDescriptor_](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/type/descriptor/java/UrlTypeDescriptor.html) for URIs. After that mapping of URI type fields are done transparently.